# NHibernate HQL queries

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

How to write HQL queries using NHibernate. What namespaces will I have to included so that everything works fine. Actually I have 2 tables Ticket and Trip and I wanta count of all the records in Trip that do not have a corresponding entry in Ticket. There is a tid field in ticket that refrences Trip id. Can anybody please explain me from start how will I write a NHibernate HQL query for this?

Comment: Have you tried searching google for this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any special namespaces to use HQL. Just create a simple NHibernate project and you can start writing HQL right away.

Here is an example from the new [NHibernate 3.0 Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/nhibernate-3-0-cookbook/book?utm_source=jasondentler.com&utm_medium=blog&utm_content=authorsite&utm_campaign=mdb_004974) and you should also check the Nhibernate in Action book which has a more elaborate examples on HQL.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate;

namespace ExecutableHQL
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
      var nhConfig = new Configuration().Configure();
      var sessionFactory = nhConfig.BuildSessionFactory();

      using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
      {
        using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
          int count = (int) session.CreateQuery("select count(*) from Trip").UniqueResult();

          tx.Commit();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public int GetCount()
    {
        var myQuery = session.CreateQuery(@" 
        select COUNT(*) from Table as t where 
        t.Id = :Id");
        myQuery.SetParameter("Id", this.Id);
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(myQuery.UniqueResult());
        return count;
    }
```